# Word or words to describe type of garments relating to football strips?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase for use in filtering football strips in an on-line store that describe both of the following.

1. A word or couple of words to distinguish between home/away/third products
2. A word or couple of words to distinguish between shirts/shorts/socks

If you imagine each of those is a item in a filter, what could the name of the filter be?

The only phrases that we have been able to come up with is "Kit Type" or "Product Type" -- "Kit Type" is acceptable but ideally we'd like to avoid "Product Type".

e.g.

> Kit Type
>   [x] Home
>   [ ] Away
>   [ ] Third
>
> Product Type
>   [ ] Shirt
>   [x] Shorts
>   [ ] Socks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns choosing a name for software variables.

Comment: @Chenmunka This is the text visible to a user, not the name for variables. We are struggling to find a term in the English language to describe something. Surely this is the purpose of this site and where the text is displayed is irrelevant? If not where would you suggest I ask this?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what a "football strip" is supposed to be.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Yes, I understand each individual word, but have no idea what they mean together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid the word "type" because it's completely generic and doesn't give any information about the classification being used (the same would be true of "category").

If your aim is that the title of the input gives the user some clue as to what the options might be within that input, then I would go with these options:

```
Home/Away
[x] Home
[ ] Away
[ ] Third

Garment
[ ] Shirt
[x] Shorts
[ ] Socks
```

"Garment" is the best word I can think of for "Category of clothing, based on which part of the body you wear it on", which is what the second option represents.