# Seeking Generic Word: Place where opponents fight

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice

I have a definition in need of a word: A *universal* term for a place where opponents compete. Unfortunately, most words are specific to one type of sport or combat, but I can't think of one that would apply universally.

Limited examples: Boxers fight in a boxing ring; MMA fighters have a cage or octagon. A circus act has a ring, card players have a table, cars have racetracks, punk rockers have mosh pits, and politicians have districts.

The significant constraint is that it has to be a place with a boundary or demarcation, and the only people inside these places (excluding support personnel) are the opponents.

Comment: A little background on the question: I'm writing software and need a name for a variable. In coding, the shorter the better -- even if it ends up being two words instead of one.

Comment: Could combine my and jimm's answers and use combatArena.

Comment: Maybe Battlefield? Battleground?  The mosh pit example is a bit off, i don't think that's supposed to be fighting?

Comment: Funny you should mention mosh pits. They're often quite bloody.

Comment: Interesting you were after a software variable, which seemed to be frowned upon based on a [question of mine](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/312155/word-or-words-to-describe-type-of-garments-relating-to-football-strips). Does anyone know the stance on this? Mine is the application of the word shouldn't influence the validity of the question.

Comment: @rrrr I think the general stance is that a single-word-request is okay as long as the asker includes an example of where they will use it. I don't think there's necessarily anything wrong with it in the context of naming a variable in software.

Comment: Why limit yourself to a single word if two will be more descriptive? "Fighting place", or "fight_location", something like that.

Comment: Interesting how 'frowning upon' would be a constraint to some. Whether it's wordsmithing or nuclear fission, the audience and context do indeed matter more than detached purists. What Howard Cosell considered his most erudite descriptions were merely pretentious pontifications to me. But when verbally sparring with Mohammed Ali, he rose to the occasion. Sometimes the application is more important than the academic.

Comment: @rrrr I've asked about this before, though I'm not as good at locating the comment in the site as some. The main idea communicated to me then was that good ELU posts should be applicable in more than just the OP's context. The main reason for the *frowning* is that variable names tend to be specific to their own context. Even so, I think ELU regulars would agree that if the question can be asked in such a way that it is independent of a programming context, the existence or otherwise of said context is irrelevant. To me, the OP's question passes this test.

Comment: These days in software development, it seems that longer, descriptive variable names for human readability and clarity are more desirable. What was x again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many great suggestions -- thanks everyone! While many suggestions were close to the mark, the variety of respective definitions were definitely food for thought.

The best choice for me: ***Crucible***.

Comment: I'm glad you found what you wanted, but can you explain briefly how this word works for you? Definition? Example sentence? No?

Comment: I'm as glad as NVZ is that you managed to answer your own question, but I feel I should point out that crucible is a term for the situation of conflict, not the location at which it takes place.

Comment: @NVC I found a definition for Crucible: a place or occasion of severe test or trial. At least in this definition (powered by Google), it fits.

Answer (score 121):

You appear to be looking for an [***arena***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arena).

> a place or scene of activity, debate, or conflict.
>   <sub>*Merriam Webster*</sub>

Comment: I did consider _Arena_, but this word doesn't necessarily exclude the spectators. Per the reference, "_a building for sports and other forms of entertainment that has a large central area surrounded by seats._"(_Once inside the arena, we could clearly see the boxing ring._) Pretty good, though and thanks.

Comment: The spectators aren't usually in the arena itself, but in a viewing area surrounding it. If you wanted another viable alternative, consider **battleground**, though that has a more war-centric connotation and wouldn't work for everything.

Comment: I agree that battleground is very close, yet war-centric. It may be the eventual choice since military terms are often borrowed; e.g. "battleground states" in an election cycle.

Comment: @JohnClifford  In current AmE usage, _arena_ often describes the entire venue. This is particularly true when discussing the [NBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_National_Basketball_Association_arenas) and [NHL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_National_Hockey_League_arenas).

Comment: +1 for arena. While an arena can be a building (which is built to be a place for competition and spectating), the word arena could be used metaphorically to mean anywhere that you're going to compete, even without the more general definition.

Comment: The term "arena shooter" or "arena fps" is sometimes used to describe less-realistic competitive FPSes like Unreal Tournament, Quake 3 (subtitle: arena), Red Eclipse and so. In at least some of the Unreal Tournaments the opponents are shown entering an actual arena with an audience, from which they are teleported to a combat arena and presumably watched remotely.

Comment: On the other hand, internally all those games refer to environments as "maps", or possibly "levels". I don't think i've seen anything but those used for a scene-stored-in-a-file in an FPS engine. Internal names and user-facing names have no inherent need to match.

Comment: @StarWeaver There are MMO type games where arenas are small parts of the map where players can battle and people can stand outside of the arena and watch, so I think arena is the more general term. The game Black Desert Online has an area with a fence around it; if you walk into it you are attackable by other players and if you stay outside it you are not (generally - the exact details aren't important) and it's called an arena by players even though it's not named on the map of the region.

Comment: I saw the question on the hot questions list and instantly assumed that "arena" was excluded as a choice. I can't think of a more appropriate word.

Comment: +1, best answer. I upvoted a few of these, but 'arena' is definitely the one I was looking for before I started reading answers.

Comment: My first gold badge! Thanks for your upvotes everyone. :D

Comment: @KiloVoltaire Consider this [famous quote from T.R. Roosevelt](http://www.theodore-roosevelt.com/trsorbonnespeech.html): "The credit belongs to the man who is actually in the arena, whose face is marred by dust and sweat and blood; who strives valiantly .... his place shall never be with those cold and timid souls who neither know victory nor defeat. " Clearly spectators don't count. I would say that this is a fairly typical usage, and that in the relatively few cases where spectators *are* included (eg. when discussing a specific sports venue with "arena" in the name), context should clarify.

Answer (score 33):

[Battleground](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/battleground) is defined by Merriam Webster as:

> - a place where a battle is fought
> - an area of conflict or disagreement

This seems to meet the criteria for combatants only, and gives a defined boundary to the area.

Answer (score 21):

[Field of Battle](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/field+of+battle) is not a single word, but [Battlefield](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/battlefield) is and does fulfill most of your requirements. It is often used to describe matches between opponents other than just of actual battles;

Comment: Ah, but battlefield is!

Comment: Simply 'field' could be used to indicate field of battle, or also lend it a sports connotation.

Comment: If it doesn't need to be one word then "Field of battle" is better than "Battlefield", as it has more crossover to non-warfare contexts.

Answer (score 14):

***[Ring](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ring)*** is used to refer to a place where opponents fight, both literally and figuratively:

> - the field of competition or rivalry

Collins Dictionary

Comment: This is most often used in the context of sport, specifically boxing or wrestling.

Comment: Yeah. No one would call a soccer field a "ring".

Answer (score 5):

A **venue** simply is

> ven·ue ˈvenˌyo͞o/Submit noun the place where something happens,
>   especially an organized event such as a concert, conference, or sports
>   event. "the river could soon be the venue for a powerboat world
>   championship event"

It could be a boxing or wrestling match, a drag race, a ball game, or a concert.  Even a Donald Trump rally.  But now we're back to fighting.

Comment: This might be *too* broad of a word but it certainly fits OP's request.

Answer (score 3):

The term **stage** covers this generically, and excludes spectators:

> a raised platform in a theater, auditorium, etc., where the performers stand

[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stage)

Comment: Also a great answer, though it doesn't specify opponents competing and isn't necessarily related to combat or sport. +1 though!

Comment: There might not be a word that carries all this weight ... maybe "fighting stage" or "combat stage"?

Comment: I was wondering that too. Hopefully one of the possibilities we've stated will meet OP's requirement. :)

Comment: There might be some mining possible around garrison or battlement, that wanders more into this territory, but I haven't found it.

Comment: "field of battle" is sometimes used as a less-warrish variant of battlefield when used idiomatically for non-combat activities, so that's another possibility.

Comment: lol ... you planted 'field of battle' in my head and I think I spit it back out as battlefield above as subconscious plagiarism. Battleground might be a close fit though.

Answer (score 3):

the word "fray", as in, "into the fray" might be of interest to you.  In old books and things this word often denote an area contest relating specifically to the combatants and is super generic!  Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks. No idea why someone down-voted you, but I bumped it back up.

Comment: @KiloVoltaire Not my down vote, but I think this answer lacks the important stuff called "reference". Without it, this should only be a comment.

Comment: I think "fray" refers to the battle itself, not the place. "Into the fray" means to join the battle, not merely step onto the field.

Answer (score 2):

***theater*** or ***theatre***

> A place that is the setting for dramatic events.
>
> [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/theater)
>
> A place or area where some important action is carried on: *a theater of war*
>
> [Merriam-Webster for Kids](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/theater)
>
> (MILITARY) ​An area or ​place in which ​important ​military ​events ​happen:
>   *a theatre of ​war*
>
> [Cambridge Dictionsries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/theatre)
>
> Any place where events take place; scene of operations; specif., an area of military operations, as in a war: *a commander in the Southern Pacific theater*
>
> [Webster's New World College Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/theater); [Collins American English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/theater)
>
> *Before the construction of the relative buildings that functioned as the city's central administration, the Forum area was the theater for gladiator combat.*
>
> [Panem et Circenses](http://www.capitolium.org/eng/imperatori/circenses.htm)

Comment: I have heard of a "theater of war".  But I don't think of my basement as a "theater of poker".

Comment: Theaters have combatants and non-combatants mixed together. I can see how the term is related, but I don't think the military sense fits well given the restriction that the only people within the boundary are opponents.

Answer (score -1):

A **stadium**

> noun
>   1.
>   a sports arena with tiers of seats for spectators.